# How do I use Linq with a HashSet of Integers to pull multiple items from a list of Objects?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a HashSet of ID numbers, stored as integers:

```
HashSet<int> IDList; // Assume that this is created with a new statement in the constructor.
```

I have a SortedList of objects, indexed by the integers found in the HashSet:

```
SortedList<int,myClass> masterListOfMyClass;
```

I want to use the HashSet to create a List as a subset of the masterListOfMyclass.

After wasting all day trying to figure out the Linq query, I eventually gave up and wrote the following, which works:

```
public List<myclass> SubSet {

        get {
            List<myClass> xList = new List<myClass>();

            foreach (int x in IDList) {
                if (masterListOfMyClass.ContainsKey(x)) {

                    xList.Add(masterListOfMyClass[x]);
                }
            }

            return xList;
        }

        private set { }
    }
```

So, I have two questions here:

1. What is the appropriate Linq query?  I'm finding Linq extremely frustrating to try to figuere out.  Just when I think I've got it, it turns around and "goes on strike".
2. Is a Linq query any better -- or worse -- than what I have written here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var xList = IDList
    .Where(masterListOfMyClass.ContainsKey)
    .Select(x => masterListOfMyClass[x])
    .ToList();
```

If your lists both have equally large numbers of items, you may wish to consider inverting the query (i.e. iterate through `masterListOfMyClass` and query `IDList`) since a `HashSet` is faster for random queries.

**Edit:**

It's less neat, but you could save a lookup into `masterListOfMyClass` with the following query, which would be a bit faster:

```
var xList = IDList
    .Select(x => { myClass y; masterListOfMyClass.TryGetValue(x, out y); return y; })
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Interesting...  as this has the potential to become quite large as the user adds to the list of objects, this could save significant time.  Thanks!

Comment: I've decided to mark this as the answer because, while the others all do accomplish the goal, I like the time-saving aspect involved with saving the lookup.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (int x in IDList.Where(x => masterListOfMyClass.ContainsKey(x)))
{
    xList.Add(masterListOfMyClass[x]);
}
```

This is the appropriate `linq` query for your loop.

Here the `linq` query will not effective in my point of view..

Comment: You are still using the foreach-loop here?

Comment: Yes.. Since an add operation is performing there. So a foreach loop need. In the other answers the ToList Conversion does the same thing.

Comment: Well the .ToList() call, depending on how the enclosing property is going to be used, is not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Linq expression:

```
List<myClass> xList = masterListOfMyClass
   .Where(x => IDList.Contains(x.Key))
   .Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

There is no big difference in the performance in such a small example, Linq is slower in general, it actually uses iterations under the hood too. The thing you get with ling is, imho, clearer code and the execution is defered until it is needed. Not i my example though, when I call .ToList().

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be (which is intentionally the same as Sankarann's first answer)

```
return (
   from x in IDList 
   where masterListOfMyClass.ContainsKey(x) 
   select masterListOfMyClass[x]
   ).ToList();
```

However, are you sure you want a `List` to be returned? Usually, when working with `IEnumerable<>` you should chain your calls using `IEnumerable<>` until the point where you actually need the data. There you can decide to e.g. loop once (use the iterator) or actually pull the data in some sort of cache using the `ToList()`, `ToArray()` etc. methods.

Also, exposing a `List<>` to the public implies that modifying this list has an impact on the calling class. I would leave it to the user of the property to decide to make a local copy or continue using the `IEnumerable<>`.
Second, as your private setter is empty, setting the 'SubSet' has no impact on the functionality. This again is confusing and I would avoid it.

An alternate (an maybe less confusing) declaration of your property might look like this

```
public IEnumerable<myclass> SubSet {
    get {
        return from x in IDList 
                where masterListOfMyClass.ContainsKey(x)
                select masterListOfMyClass[x]
    }
}
```

Comment: Re the setter - I've been getting strange (and random) error messages.  C# seems to sometimes decide that it wants a placeholder setter in some properties, but not in others.  Perhaps it's a newbie thing, but it's fussy that way.

Comment: And thanks for the tip on the ienumerable as well.  Its ultimate destination is a listView object, (which I realize probably implies an ObservableCollection)...